# Generar Ireport en un documentViewer Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, jasper-reports

Necesito saber cómo puedo generar un reporte ireport en una variable `StreamedContent`. El reporte se encuentra en un paquete en el proyecto. La  dificultad que tengo es que no puedo obtener la ruta del proyecto. Por el momento tengo esta porcion de codigo:

```
 public void generarReporte() {
    try{
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource solicitudLista = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(super.getSolicitudes());
        byte[] pdf;            
        String report = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                        .getRealPath("/com/../reportes/solicitudAspirante.jasper");
        //InputStream report =   this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("");
        //JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reporte);
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap(),solicitudLista);
        pdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
        this.archivo.setFile(new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf), "application/pdf"));  
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Se supone que en la variable `report` debería de cargar el reporte compilado pero no se encuentra en la ruta especificada. ¿Como puedo hacer para cargar el reporte?

Comment: OP deberías agregar tu código por medio de la herramienta, no por medio de una imagen

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta. Muchas gracias por el consejo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo utilizo este código para generar el reporte en un pe:documentViewer:

Genera un documento:

```
public DefaultStreamedContent getImprimeOrdenInicioStream() {
    if (ordenInicioSelected != null) {
        String reportePath = "/archivos/ordenInicio/rptOrdenInicio.jasper";
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("idOrdenInicio", ordenInicioSelected.getIdOrdenInicio());
        parametros.put("idPersona", usuario.getIdPersona().getIdPersona());

        return imprimePDFEnDocumentViewer(reportePath, parametros, "rptOrdenInicio");
    }
    return new DefaultStreamedContent();
}
```

En este método defino los parámetros del JasperReports.

Y luego llamo al otro método que se llama imprimeDPFEnDocumentViewer:

```
public DefaultStreamedContent imprimePDFEnDocumentViewer(String rutaReporte, Map parametros, String nombreReporte) {
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;

    try {
        // Obteniendo las rutas relativas de los archivos necesarios
        String reportePath = sc.getRealPath(rutaReporte);
        String logoPath = sc.getRealPath("/resources/images/logo.png");
        String escudoPath = sc.getRealPath("/resources/images/escudo.png");
        parametros.put("logo_isbm", logoPath);
        parametros.put("escudo_logo", escudoPath);
        parametros.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);

        // Obteniendo la conexion del JDNI
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        if (initialContext == null) {
            System.out.println("Problema con el JNDI. No se puede obtener el InitialContext.");
        }
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
        if (datasource != null) {
            conn = datasource.getConnection();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error al buscar el datasource.");
        }

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportePath, parametros, conn);

        // Mostrando el documento
        byte[] docPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(docPdf), "application/pdf", nombreReporte);

    } catch (JRException | NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GeneraReportes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("No se puede obtener la conexion: " + ex);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GeneraReportes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Todas las rutas son relativas.

Luego en el xhtml lo llamo de la siguiente manera:

En un botón de un

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-print" title="#{msg.imprimir}" process="@this" oncomplete="PF('wDia').show()" update=":dia" rendered="true">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{inicio}" target="#{generaReportes.ordenInicioSelected}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

La variable `#{inicio}` es el atributo `var` del dataTable y `#{generaReportes.ordenInicioSelected}` es una variable en bean que lo genera, que se utiliza en el código que puse arriba.

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Ah y se me olvidó poner la parte del pe:documentViewer

Answer (score 0):

Escribo la clase creada, para que otras personas puedan utilizarla.

```
public class GenerarReporte {

private Map<String, Object> parameters;
private String reportPath;

public GenerarReporte(Map<String, Object> parameters, String reportPath) {
    this.reportPath = reportPath;
    this.parameters = parameters;
}

public DefaultStreamedContent generarReporte() {
    DefaultStreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent();
    if (this.parameters != null && this.reportPath != null) {
        file = imprimePDFEnDocumentViewer(this.reportPath, this.parameters, "reporte");
    }
    return file;
}

private DefaultStreamedContent imprimePDFEnDocumentViewer(String rutaReporte, Map parameters, String nombreReporte) {
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    DefaultStreamedContent content = new DefaultStreamedContent();
    byte[] docPdf;
    try {
        // Obteniendo las rutas relativas de los archivos necesarios
        ExternalContext sc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        String reportePath = sc.getRealPath(rutaReporte);
        //JRBeanCollectionDataSource datasourcesFields = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(fields);           
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportePath, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
        // Mostrando el documento
        docPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        content = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(docPdf), "application/pdf", nombreReporte);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return content;
}
```

}